# How to query multiple tables for certain columns using an ID in both tables

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

These are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Movies 
(
    movieID        INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    movieName      STRING,
    runTime        STRING,
    parentalRating STRING,
    starRating     INTEGER
)
WITHOUT ROWID;

CREATE TABLE Theatre 
(
    theatreID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    location  STRING
)
WITHOUT ROWID;

CREATE TABLE Schedule 
(
    scheduleID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    movieID    INTEGER REFERENCES Movies (movieID),
    theatreID  INTEGER REFERENCES Theatre (theatreID),
    date       DATE,
    time       TIME
)
WITHOUT ROWID;
```

This is my query:

```
scheduleQuery = '''Select scheduleID, movieName, location, date, time
                   From Schedule, Movies, Theatre
                   Where movieName = Movies.movieID and location = Theatre.theatreID
                '''
```

This query doesn't return anything and I am trying to get it to return the data in the schedule table but with the movie name in place of the `movieID` and the `theatre` location in place of the `theatreID`.

What query should I do to achieve that?

Comment: Take a look at your data. Is it possible that these equalities: `movieName=Movies.movieID` and `location=Theatre.theatreID` to be true?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT 
s.scheduleID,
m.movieName, 
t.location,
s.date, 
s.time
FROM
Schedule s
INNER JOIN Movies m on m.movieID = s.movieID
INNER JOIN Theatre t on t.theatreID = s.theatreID
```